# Javascript, replace first word in sentence in class

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to assist on how replace the first name in the name class with Marty. I would like to only use Javascript not jQuery.

So this should result in " Marty Clock " instead.

```
<span class="name">Brad Clock</span>
```

This is what i've got right now.

```js
const article = document.querySelector('article');
const name = article.querySelectorAll('.name');


for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
 const text = name[i].textContent.split(" ").replace([0], ' ').join("Marty")

 console.log(text);



}
```

```html
<article>
   
   <p>Does your mom know about tomorrow night? Good morning, Mom. Oh, <span class="name">Marty</span>, I almost forgot, <span class="name">Jennifer Parker</span> called. He's alright. Hey c'mon, I had to change, you think I'm going back in that zoot suit? The <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/film-back-to-the-future-anniversary2015-Y1aL1fxTEbhQs" art="Spooky young man">old man</a> really came through it worked. <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/FrVlu71LVoVXy" alt="I guess you guys aren't ready for that yet">I have to tell you about the future</a>.</p>
   
   <p>He's absolutely right, <span class="name">Marty</span>. the last thing you need is headaches. Well, I guess that's everything. Please note that <span class="name">Einstein's</span> clock is in complete synchronization with my control watch. Good evening, I'm Doctor <span class="name">Emmet Brown</span>, I'm standing here on the parking lot of- What did you sleep in your clothes again last night.</p>
   <p>Precisely. <span class="name">George</span>,  Hey beat it, spook, this don't concern you. <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/back-to-the-future-behind-scenes-CdAh3Sh0Mvtdu" alt="I'm flying!">Bet your ass it works.</a> Here you go, lady. There's a quarter.</p>
  </article>
```

Comment: You meant first **word** in sentence?

Comment: check my answer. other's are incorrect as they would replace `Einstein's` with Marty instead of `Marty's`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex `/[^\s']*/` matches everything up to `whitespace` or `'` character. Used `Array.prototype.forEach()` for convinience.

```js
var names = document.querySelectorAll('.name');

names.forEach((name) => {

  name.innerText = name.innerText.replace(/[^\s]*/, 'Marty')

})
```

```html
<article>
   
   <p>Does your mom know about tomorrow night? Good morning, Mom. Oh, <span class="name">Marty</span>, I almost forgot, <span class="name">Jennifer Parker</span> called. He's alright. Hey c'mon, I had to change, you think I'm going back in that zoot suit? The <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/film-back-to-the-future-anniversary2015-Y1aL1fxTEbhQs" art="Spooky young man">old man</a> really came through it worked. <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/FrVlu71LVoVXy" alt="I guess you guys aren't ready for that yet">I have to tell you about the future</a>.</p>
   
   <p>He's absolutely right, <span class="name">Marty</span>. the last thing you need is headaches. Well, I guess that's everything. Please note that <span class="name">Einstein's</span> clock is in complete synchronization with my control watch. Good evening, I'm Doctor <span class="name">Emmet Brown</span>, I'm standing here on the parking lot of- What did you sleep in your clothes again last night.</p>
   <p>Precisely. <span class="name">George</span>,  Hey beat it, spook, this don't concern you. <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/back-to-the-future-behind-scenes-CdAh3Sh0Mvtdu" alt="I'm flying!">Bet your ass it works.</a> Here you go, lady. There's a quarter.</p>
  </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the one what you want, isn't it?

```js
const article = document.querySelector('article');
const name = article.querySelectorAll('.name');

for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
 var texts = name[i].textContent.split(" ");
 texts[0] = "Marty";
 console.log(texts.join(" "));
}
```

```html
<article>
   
   <p>Does your mom know about tomorrow night? Good morning, Mom. Oh, <span class="name">Marty</span>, I almost forgot, <span class="name">Jennifer Parker</span> called. He's alright. Hey c'mon, I had to change, you think I'm going back in that zoot suit? The <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/film-back-to-the-future-anniversary2015-Y1aL1fxTEbhQs" art="Spooky young man">old man</a> really came through it worked. <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/FrVlu71LVoVXy" alt="I guess you guys aren't ready for that yet">I have to tell you about the future</a>.</p>
   
   <p>He's absolutely right, <span class="name">Marty</span>. the last thing you need is headaches. Well, I guess that's everything. Please note that <span class="name">Einstein's</span> clock is in complete synchronization with my control watch. Good evening, I'm Doctor <span class="name">Emmet Brown</span>, I'm standing here on the parking lot of- What did you sleep in your clothes again last night.</p>
   <p>Precisely. <span class="name">George</span>,  Hey beat it, spook, this don't concern you. <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/back-to-the-future-behind-scenes-CdAh3Sh0Mvtdu" alt="I'm flying!">Bet your ass it works.</a> Here you go, lady. There's a quarter.</p>
  </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here

```
 const text = name[i].textContent.split(" ").replace([0], ' ').join("Marty")
```

as *name[i].textContent.split(" ")* returns an array and you can't replace a string on a array.

You might want to have

```
var text = name[i].textContent.split(" "); //gets the words
text.splice(0, 1, 'Marty'); //removes first and replaces with Marty
text.join(" "); //converts the array in string adding spaces
```

Comment: would replace Einstein's with Marty instead of Marty's

Comment: You can just use this markup `<span class="name">Einstein</span>'s` instead of the original one and problem is solved with less coding.

Answer (score 0):

use of regex replace should be on string like:

```
name[i].textContent.replace(/\w+/, 'Marty')
```

```js
const article = document.querySelector('article');
const name = article.querySelectorAll('.name');


for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
 const text = name[i].textContent.replace(/\w+/, 'Marty');

 console.log(text);



}
```

```html
<article>
   
   <p>Does your mom know about tomorrow night? Good morning, Mom. Oh, <span class="name">Marty</span>, I almost forgot, <span class="name">Jennifer Parker</span> called. He's alright. Hey c'mon, I had to change, you think I'm going back in that zoot suit? The <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/film-back-to-the-future-anniversary2015-Y1aL1fxTEbhQs" art="Spooky young man">old man</a> really came through it worked. <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/FrVlu71LVoVXy" alt="I guess you guys aren't ready for that yet">I have to tell you about the future</a>.</p>
   
   <p>He's absolutely right, <span class="name">Marty</span>. the last thing you need is headaches. Well, I guess that's everything. Please note that <span class="name">Einstein's</span> clock is in complete synchronization with my control watch. Good evening, I'm Doctor <span class="name">Emmet Brown</span>, I'm standing here on the parking lot of- What did you sleep in your clothes again last night.</p>
   <p>Precisely. <span class="name">George</span>,  Hey beat it, spook, this don't concern you. <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/back-to-the-future-behind-scenes-CdAh3Sh0Mvtdu" alt="I'm flying!">Bet your ass it works.</a> Here you go, lady. There's a quarter.</p>
  </article>
```

Comment: Why is the actual text not changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` for doing it:

```
let split = "Brad Clock".split(' ');
split[0].replace("Brad", "Marty").join(' ');
```

**Update**: Here's the code for replacing content of the article:

```
const article = document.querySelector('article');
const name = article.querySelectorAll('.name');

for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
     const split = name[i].innerHTML.split(' ');
     split[0] = "Brad";
     name[i].innerHTML = split.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: would replace Einstein's with Marty instead of Marty's

Answer (score 0):

Here is on way of doing it :
get the content of each element of the given class and replace the first word with Marty

```js
function replaceNames(className,newName){
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("."+className);
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
 var content = elements[i].innerHTML;
 if(content!=""){
  var arr = content.split(" ");
  if(arr.length >0){
   arr[0] = newName;
   content = arr.join(" ");
   elements[i].innerHTML = content;
  }
 }
}
}

replaceNames("name","Marty");
```

```html
<article>
   <p>Does your mom know about tomorrow night? Good morning, Mom. Oh, <span class="name">Marty</span>, I almost forgot, <span class="name">Jennifer Parker</span> called. He's alright. Hey c'mon, I had to change, you think I'm going back in that zoot suit? The <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/film-back-to-the-future-anniversary2015-Y1aL1fxTEbhQs" art="Spooky young man">old man</a> really came through it worked. <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/FrVlu71LVoVXy" alt="I guess you guys aren't ready for that yet">I have to tell you about the future</a>.</p>
   
   <p>He's absolutely right, <span class="name">Marty</span>. the last thing you need is headaches. Well, I guess that's everything. Please note that <span class="name">Einstein's</span> clock is in complete synchronization with my control watch. Good evening, I'm Doctor <span class="name">Emmet Brown</span>, I'm standing here on the parking lot of- What did you sleep in your clothes again last night.</p>
   <p>Precisely. <span class="name">George</span>,  Hey beat it, spook, this don't concern you. <a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/back-to-the-future-behind-scenes-CdAh3Sh0Mvtdu" alt="I'm flying!">Bet your ass it works.</a> Here you go, lady. There's a quarter.</p>
</article>
```